# The vibrate mode on my phone will not work

Tags: htc

My phone will not vibrate on vibrate mode. It will not vibrate on the sound mode (which is what I have it set on). When i get a text or notification it has to be on full volume to make a sound or silent. It will not vibrate at all, not for a call or for a text. and my phone is HTC desire 810